# How to chain jquery Deferreds

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Lets say I have the following Deferred setting:

```
var dfr = new Deferred()

dfr.done(step1)
.then(step2)
.then(step3)
```

is there a way to pass the result of `step2` into `step3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Assuming `step1`, `step2` and `step3` to be javascript functions, then simply get `step2` to return its result and it automatically becomes a parameter passed to `step3`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass the result .lets see an example of downloading the files so that it will be clear to you..

```
 fun5().then(
            function (msg) {
            if(msg==='m1'){
            var dfd1 = $.Deferred(function (dfd1){
             //alert("called2");

            var remoteFile = "http://www.freegreatdesign.com/files/images/6/2921-large-apple-icon-png-3.jpg";
            var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
            var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
            if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
            localPath = localPath.substring(7);
            }

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.download(remoteFile, localPath, function(entry) {
            dfd1.resolve('m2');
            // Do what you want with successful file downloaded and then
            // call the method again to get the next file
            //downloadFile();
            }, fail);
            }, fail);
            }, fail);

            //alert("In 2");
            });

            }
            return dfd1.promise();
            }).then(
            function (msg) {
            if(msg==='m2'){
            var dfd2 = $.Deferred(function (dfd2){
             //alert("called3");

            var remoteFile = "http://www.freegreatdesign.com/files/images/6/2921-large-apple-icon-png-3.jpg";
            var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
            var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
            if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
            localPath = localPath.substring(7);
            }

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.download(remoteFile, localPath, function(entry) {
            dfd2.resolve('m3');
            // Do what you want with successful file downloaded and then
            // call the method again to get the next file
            //downloadFile();
            }, fail);
            }, fail);
            }, fail);

            //alert("In 3");
            });

            }
            return dfd2.promise();
            })
```